# Is there a free dataset of historical geocoordinates of ancient cities and places?

Tags: data, geojson, csv, history

Is there a freely available dataset (csv, geojson, topojson, etc.) with geocoordinates of ancient cities, for example of the Roman Empire? Ideally with additional information like population size?

I've searched GeoCommons and NaturalEarth but found nothing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest [Pleiades](http://pleiades.stoa.org/) as the best option to start with. Lots of data, open source implementation, and you can upload too. You can [download](http://pleiades.stoa.org/downloads) in CSV, KML and other formats. You may need to work the links to get supporting data such as population size - I don't know of anything that does that kind of time-varying data across the ancient world.

If you particularly want maps, [David Rumsey](http://www.davidrumsey.com/) is worth a look. ECAI ([wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_Cultural_Atlas_Initiative), since [primary site](http://www.ecai.org/) appears down) might also be worth checking for your particular domain needs.